# Groovy extract substring

Tags: groovy

Below is the string I have

```
author = "59612934+firstname-lastname-ok@users.noreply.github.com"
```

How can I get just the firstname and lastname from the above string. The string after lastname will always be `-ok`

Desired Output:

```
author = "firstname.lastname"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it with regex replacement like

```
String author = "59612934+firstname-lastname-ok@users.noreply.github.com"
assert 'firstname.lastname' == author.replaceFirst( /\d+\+([^-]+)-([^-]+)-ok.*/, '$1.$2' )
```